# PRISM: Passing object/events from parent to child View/VM with PopupRegions

Tags: events, mvvm, prism

We are working with an application that uses prism and MVVM for healthcare tracking operations.

Within this application, we have registered views in primary regions, and scenarios in which clicking on a cell in a grid (in this case a xamdatagrid - Infragistics) will launch another region via the prism region popup behaviors constructs.

So, when we click on the cell, a cellactivation operation in the code behind for that view is called which then calls a method in the view model to .RequestNavigate to the view that is registered for the 'secondary' popup region (thus launching what appears to be a dialog over the existing application).

I am attempting to pass an object from the parent view (the values of the record in the grid) to the child view that is launched in the popup, and have found that none of the expected operations is working.

I have a mediator object that we are using to pass information back from children to parents, but this does not work the other direction because the publish/notify operations for the mediator require the child view to 'already' be instantiated before the parent publishes to pass that information.

I'm finding that the event aggregator structures built into the Prism.Events classes don't appear to be working either (I'm assuming because of the same publish/subscribe issues). I can publish an event through the event aggregator from the parent view and subscribe in the child view, but I have to launch the child view 'twice' in order to get the event tied to the event aggregator operation to actually fire.

I understand this is rather vague (minus the code), but I'm looking more for a start point, or anyone that's run into the same kinds of issues. The bullet point scenario is as follows:

- Parent view already instantiated in existing region.
- Clicking on cell in parent view instantiates (navigates to) child view in popup region.
- Same click operation needs to pass an object from the parent view to the child view so that the child view can filter its own data based on that object.
- Operations are constructed using Prism/MVVM.

Any help, suggestions, pointers, ideas would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same scenario and ended up with creating a UiService that are injected to our ViewModels. Our ViewModel base class has a SetModel method which the UiService calls when navigating, for sending parameters to the destination view.

By example:

Clicking a button in the existing View.

Source ViewModel calls UiService ShowView(data).

UiService calls RequestNavigate for the requested view.

UiService calls SetModel on the destination ViewModel (by accessing the DataContext of the requested view) to pass in the data from the source ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you want to pass it can be pretty simple with `INavigationAware`

Sounds like you want to pass something like query string - parameters, etc. Code to open window will be like this:

```
    var query = new UriQuery
        {
            { "MailItemKey", this.SelectedMailItem.MailItemKey.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }
        };

    RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.Popup, typeof(MailItemView).Name + query.ToString());
```

And inside `MailItemViewModel` which is our popup's VM code is like this:

```
public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            var mailItemKey = int.Parse(navigationContext.Parameters["MailItemKey"]);

            }
```

If you want to pass custom objects - it will be more complex. I would look for `MVVM in the box` samples - there is some code on how it's done. I had to re-work it whole lot and code is not really copy-pasteable.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the PopupRegion has not been used before.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect use of a RegionContext.

Parent view contains a region that can have multiple "child" views activated in it. They need to share some context or data. Set a region context and bind or pass whatever info all the "child" views in the Region will need.

See the Prism samples around RegionContext.